# Bitwise operator in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How would I write the following SQL query in SQLAlchemy involving a bitwise and?

```sql
select * from table where flags & 1 = 1;
```

Where `table` is the table name, and `flags` is the column name in that table.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You want to use the bitwise operator like this:

```
session.query(User).filter(somecolumn.op('&')(1) == 1)
```

You can write something similar for OR:

```
session.query(User).filter(somecolumn.op('|')(4) > 4)
```